# Allow products to be bought by specific users

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, configurable-product, sku

I've a configurable product with options every option has its own sku I need to let this sku to be available to buy only by a specific USER or USER GROUP.

Is this possible to do in some way? With cart rules or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in Vinais Groupcatalog extension that lets you hide products or categories depending on customer group.
https://github.com/Vinai/groupscatalog2

I know this is a different approach as you mentioned but maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this with cart rules. You would require a custom module to apply logic to your configurable product so that the specific options are then displayed to the appropriate customer group. Information in this similar question might be useful.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28575625/how-to-display-selected-products-based-on-customer-group-in-magento